# Make computed property available to all components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Is there a way to make a computed property available globally ?

For example: let's say there is an 'isAdmin' property in Vuex store that we can access with a getter. And this property is used in many components for conditional rendering. How do I make it available to all components instead of declaring it in every component computed properties ?

Comment: Use an Event Hub as suggested in the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html?#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced

Comment: create a mixin and register it globally

Comment: How about `this.$store.getters.isAdmin`? Or have a look at the [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) helper.

Comment: @YomS. The question is not how to access a store property, the question is how to have this property directly available in all components template without having to add the getter in every components computeds. Nguyen You's above suggestion is well thought

Comment: @mohsen I agree, Nguyen You's suggestion is a good one, and it's also true that `this.$store.getters.isAdmin` is directly accessible across all components without needing registration.

Answer (score 5):

It has already been suggested that you could do this using a global mixin. That will work but it isn't the only way.

While it is unlikely to make a significant impact on performance, it seems a little wasteful to use a computed property for this. Every component will have its own computed property and each will keep a cached copy of the value. But the values will all be the same.

Further, the store getter will already be caching the value at that stage, so caching at the computed property level isn't really saving us anything.

Instead we can add a JavaScript property getter to the Vue prototype that proxies through to store property. It isn't technically a computed property but it will work much the same:

```js
// These 5 lines are the important bit, the rest is just for demonstration purposes
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$isAdmin', {
  get () {
    return this.$store.getters.isAdmin
  }
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isAdmin: false
  },
  
  mutations: {
    toggle (state) {
      state.isAdmin = !state.isAdmin
    }
  },
  
  getters: {
    isAdmin (state) {
      return state.isAdmin
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  
  methods: {
    onClick () {
      this.$store.commit('toggle')
    }
  },
  
  watch: {
    $isAdmin () {
      console.log('$isAdmin watcher triggered')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ $isAdmin }}</p>
  <button @click="onClick">Change</button>
</div>
```

There is one potentially major hurdle. As Vuex uses a Vue instance internally an `isAdmin` property defined on the prototype would clash with the automatically generated computed property used behind-the-scenes by Vuex for the `isAdmin` getter. In the example above I have dodged that problem by calling the component property `$isAdmin` instead. This problem can, in theory, also be avoided by defining the prototype property after the store is created.